# Ignoring... Layers with arguments in `__init__` must override `get_config`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm training a convolutional neural network using residual units defined by the class below (as per page 478 in "Hands On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras and Tensorflow" by Aurelien Geron)

```
class ResidualUnit(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, filters, strides=1, activation="relu", **kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.activation = tf.keras.activations.get(activation)

        self.main_layers = [
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, 3, strides=strides, padding="same", use_bias=False),
            tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
            self.activation,
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, 3, strides=1, padding="same", use_bias=False),
            tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()]

        self.skip_layers=[]

        if strides > 1:
            self.skip_layers = [
                tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, 1, strides=strides, padding="same", use_bias=False),
                tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()]


    def call(self, inputs):

        Z = inputs

        for layer in self.main_layers:
            Z = layer(Z)
        skip_Z = inputs

        for layer in self.skip_layers:
            skip_Z = layer(skip_Z)

        return self.activation(Z + skip_Z)
```

The class is created without error, and the model architecture (using this class) is created without error:

```
ResNet_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

ResNet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, strides=2, input_shape=num_pixels_and_channels,
                                       padding="same", use_bias=False))


ResNet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

ResNet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu"))

ResNet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))

prev_filters=64

for filters in [64] * 1 + [128] * 1 + [256] * 1 + [512] * 1:
    strides = 1 if filters == prev_filters else 2
    ResNet_model.add(ResidualUnit(filters, strides=strides))
    prev_filters=filters

ResNet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool2D())
ResNet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
ResNet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(257, activation="softmax"))
```

...but when I train the model, a warning is displayed as soon as the training begins:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Model failed to serialize as JSON. Ignoring... Layers with arguments in `__init__` must override `get_config`.

The model trains for the 1st epoch and then stops.

What is wrong and what do I need to change in my code to fix this?

I am running tensorflow version 2.1.0 in a Jupyter Notebook on a CPU.

Comment: I'm actually also facing a similar issue

Answer (score 10):

I overided the get_config() function as follows in my layer class and it seemed to have solved the issue:

```
def get_config(self):
    cfg = super().get_config()
    return cfg
```

More concretely:

```
class AttentionBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self,units = 32,**kwargs):
    super(AttentionBlock, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.units = units
    self.conv2d = tf.keras.layers.SeparableConv2D(self.units, 1,  padding='same',
                                  use_bias=True,
                                  kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling(), bias_initializer='zeros',
                                  bias_regularizer=None)
    self.relu = tf.keras.layers.Activation('swish')
    self.batchnorm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()


def get_config(self):
    cfg = super().get_config()
    return cfg    

def call(self,inputs):
  if type(inputs) is not list or len(inputs) <= 1:
        raise Exception('Merge must be called on a list of tensors '
                        '(at least 2). Got: ' + str(inputs))
  else:
      x,y = inputs
      w = self.conv2d(x)
      v = self.conv2d(y)
      out = self.relu(w + v)
      out = self.batchnorm(out)
      out = tf.nn.sigmoid(out)
      return out
```

Comment: Thanks HuckleberryFinn! I'll try this to see if it works for me.

Comment: I've not had chance to re-try yet. I'm working on another project now (I posted this question 2 months ago) and just started a new job too so short on time and headspace at the mo. I'll comment here when I've tried your answer and accept it if it works.